# Text editor that has special characters

Tags: text-editor

I am looking for a text editor for any type of ubuntu, that has a wide variety of symbols or special characters that I can use in the text editor.

Thanks.

Comment: Text editor is just software that holds whatever text user is giving. It's not up to the editor to have these character sets available. Can you be more specific about the characters you're looking for.

Comment: Ŝ   ʃ    ʄ   ʅʒ ʕ ʘ ʡʢ ɸ Ѩ

Stuff like that. No need to be exactly these ones.

Comment: Does no one know how to use similar symbols as those above in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be a bit late, but anyway. Any text editor that supports utf-8 should be able to handle any unicode character. This includes gedit, Kate and leafpad. The only exception I can think of off the top of my head is IDLE which can't display characters not found in the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. The hard part is writing the characters if they aren't on the keyboard. One option on Ubuntu is to click the button near the top-right corner of the screen that changes the keyboard language, then click "Character map". You may want to resize the window slightly and then change the width of the language list though. Note that I have my keyboard set to Spanish, so where you see "Es" on my screenshot, it may say something different on your screen. The character map can also be launched by searching for it. Another to write characters not on your keyboard layout is to find their unicode codepoint in hexadecimal (e.g 1f337 for  or 15d for ŝ. Once you know that code, you can press control-shift-u, type the code and press space. There is of course also the option of copy-pasting characters from some document that already contains them.

[Character Map item selected from keyboard layout pop-up menu in the top right corner of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtPqj.png)

It's worth noting that some keyboard layouts may be different from how they are on Windows, for example if I press a, s, d and f with the Spanish keyboard layout whilst holding down Alt Gr (that's the "right alt key" on English keyboards), I get æ, ß, ð and đ, even though those are not used in Spanish or in any of the Spanish regional languages. So you may want to check out some of the layouts in case one of them contains the characters you need. It's generally faster to type something than to have to find it on a list.